# POST Request getting "405 Method Not Allowed" in AWS S3 react app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-405

I've just deployed a react app through aws s3 website hosting. Everything went fine until the app makes a POST to my server and it returns this error

```bash
405 Method Not Allowed

 - Code: MethodNotAllowed
 - Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
 - Method: POST
 - ResourceType: OBJECT
 - RequestId: GWHR7Z0XGRXPVC9Z
 - HostId: 7Kfxe3uk6TfN7RBHfL/XzhdLwO5qYh1yE2ucdPrMRaz5lvT+UqP1Z6OezVvkc5a+K8RFn2JUnoY=
```

Reading some documentation, I found this `Supports only GET and HEAD requests on objects` describing Website endpoint in S3. The error make sense but this is the first time I am getting it and I've deployed a lot of apps through S3 and never faced this problem before.

This means that I can't connect my server hosting my app through S3?
Can I do something to fix it like allowing POST requests? (didn't find any info about this one)

My bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've found something about signing the POST request may help but I am not really sure if this is the case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You tend to see this issue when you don't have the correct bucket policy added or the IAM role/credentials making the request do not have the required policies attached to the role possibly.

You mention POST request but what is the action you are trying to complete? Is it post an object into the bucket or modify the resource properties?

Comment: Hi @ Dean Foran, I'm trying to make a POST request from the react app to get some data from the server. I've updated the question with my bucket policy.

Comment: Hi Michal,

Object retrieval uses a GET operation not a POST operation against the bucket. Your parameters are then passed as query strings in the GET request.

Example: `/Key+?partNumber=PartNumber&response-cache-control=ResponseCacheControl&response-content-disposition=ResponseContentDisposition&response-content-encoding=ResponseContentEncoding&response-content-language=ResponseContentLanguage&response-content-type=ResponseContentType&response-expires=ResponseExpires&versionId=VersionId`

See more details [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)

Comment: Thanks @Dean Foran, I ended up migrating to Amplify to host my app. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great Move!! :)